# How to detect lost MySQL server but still allow for long running queries

Tags: java, mysql, sockets, jdbc

I have a standard jdbc connection between a java application and a mysql server.

There is a configured connection timeout of 5 seconds but whenever a connection as been created and is reused (through a connection pool) the connection timeout has no part anymore.

There is also a socket timeout configured but it's set to 5 minutes to allow for some long running queries.

So, now the problem is that I can't detect an actual lost MySQL server in a shorter time than those 5 minutes.

I have an conceptual idea to set the tcp keepalive probe settings on the OS to something much lower than the default of 7200 seconds and start sending tcp probes. My problem with that solution is that it affects every thing on the application server and I would, ideally, like to only affect my own app.

Is there no way to have the jdbc driver also send keep alive probes to detect if the server is down or just working?

Comment: *"There is also a socket timeout configured but it's set to 5 minutes to allow for some long running queries."* MySQL's socket timeout is idle time (SLEEP in processlist) not query execution time to make that clear

Comment: Yes, but as far as I know there is nothing sent over the socket until the query is finished. MySQL i very "silent". If MySQL sent "still running query" every second or so it wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: MySQL does in fact has a max execution time but it works different you need to add a optimizer option `SELECT /*+ MAX_EXECUTION_TIME(1000) .. */` to give a hint how long a query  may run in this case 1 second.  See [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimizer-hints.html#optimizer-hints-execution-time)

Comment: Do you actually want to detect a broken MySQL server or wish to know if the long running query isn't stuck? In the former you could easily do a simple "select now()" to see if it's still alive.

Comment: `ping` or `select 1` suffers the same problem as all other queries, they will run until the socket times out.

Comment: @ArtvanScheppingen I wan't to detect that the server is gone. And as I just answered another `select 1` will not complete until the socket timeout either, and it's just as likely the server disappears right after the select as it is before.

Answer (score 0):

You could open a connection directly to the MySQL port (generally on 3306) and set a very short timeout on the socket. On the Java sockets there are two timeouts: the connection establishing timeout and the response timeout. The latter might pose a problem if the connection is accepted, but queued by the OS (yes this can happen with MySQL on a high connection rate). In this case set this timeout:

```
socket.setSoTimeout(timeOut);
```

This will raise a socket exception if the timeout (in milliseconds) exceeds.

MySQL is a server-first protocol, so it will immediately welcome you and tell you it's protocol and version number. You can just close the connection after this and MySQL will just handle this fine.

Comment: Sure, "outside" detection is easy. But through the driver would be much more powerful.

Comment: I agree, but in the current MySQL driver this is simply impossible. What you could do is to use the MySQL X protocol, which allows asynchronous execution.